# C++ Inserting Into Shared Pointer to Map

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr

I'm using a `std::shared_ptr<std::map<std::string,std::string> > ptr` and I'd like to insert into the map using the more familiar `map[key] = value;` approach instead of using `ptr->insert(std::map<std::string,std::string>::value_type("blah","blahh"));`. When I try `ptr["blah"] = "blahh";` or `(*ptr)["blah"] = "blahh";` the compiler throws a fit. Does anyone know how to do this? I'm fairly new to smart pointer so forgive me if this is a ridiculous question.

Comment: While it's good you use smart pointers instead of raw non-owning pointer, what is the reason to have a pointer to a container such as `std::map`? Pointers to containers are seldom a good idea.

Comment: By the way, are you *sure* that `(*ptr)["blah"] = "blahh"` gives you build errors? Because that should work fine (with the declaration of `ptr` you show).

Comment: I need to use the map in two separate threads. One thread is getting network message entries to add to the map, the other is doing something with those entries and publishing other things.

Comment: Then how about passing a *reference* to the map to each thread? Or put it in a structure together with a mutex to control its access, and pass a reference (or indeed a pointer) to that structure. Or if the thread functions are member of the same class, and called on the same object, just have the map be an ordinary member variable?

Comment: I suppose both of those are valid options, I ran across this issue and thought it was an interesting syntax question.

Comment: Well as I said above, dereferencing the pointer should work. That gives you the `std::map` object pointed to by the pointer, which you then can access normally. It's not that nice to read and write but it should work.

Comment: Ok, I'll double check my code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try to prepare a minimal example. Maybe you'll work it out while doing so, and if not, you'll have an example people can analyze.